# non-US external keyboards with ubuntu touch

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-touch, android, bluetooth, keyboard-layout

On android I've had issues with non US keyboards, they didn't work without special apps or some fiddling with system files. As ubuntu touch is based partly on open source android (cyanogenmod?), and partly on regular linux, I'm curious if it has the same problems.

I'd be interested in using both bluetooth keyboards and usb keyboards with Ubuntu touch. Will they work with a danish (or other european) keyboard layout for apple usb and bluetooth keyboards?

EDIT: I have checked and this is still a problem on android.

Answer (score 0):

My current answer is no. I can't get my UK Dell USB keyboard to work with my Meizu 4. I have reported a bug:

USB keyboard not recognized Meizu 4
Bug #1488899 reported by fcolcord on 2015-08-26

No one else has reported a similar problem, so I think the bug is asleep until someone else verifies it. Please go to [that page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-system-image/+bug/1488899) and say the bug affects you, if it does.

Comment: I don't have a device with ubuntu touch to test this with, unfortunately.